# Octave 3.8.2 how to install Image pkg?

Tags: windows, installation, octave

How to install Image pkg on Octave 3.8.2 on Windows?

Do I need to download tar archive from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/) and install it using [pkg install image.x.x.x](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html)?

But how to know which version of image pkg is compatible with Octave 3.8.2?

I tried 
`pkg install image-1.0.11.tar.gz`
but get lots of errors.

Comment: I suggest the 4.0.0 installer from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/ and then "pkg -forge -verbose install general control signal image"

Answer (score 2):

To install image pkg on Octave 3.8.2 we need to install pkgs in this order:

```
pkg install general-1.3.4.tar.gz
pkg install control-2.6.6.tar.gz
pkg install signal-1.3.0.tar.gz
pkg install image-2.2.2.tar.gz
```